# How to cache all members? Discord.Js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When i run the code below it gives only 1 member which is the bot it self. (in my test server with the bot and me.) Is there a way to refresh/update the members cache?

```
console.log(MainGuild.members.cache)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch every member in a guild with [`GuildMemberManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch)

```js
MainGuild.members.fetch().then((members) => {
 console.log(members);
 // code...
});
```

This might also be related: [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-emitting)

Comment: Thanks, it was because of the intents.

Comment: Note that as of August 2021, `.fetchMembers()` was deprecated and has been replaced by `guild.members.fetch()`

Comment: Actually, it was replaced as of March 1st, 2020.